# Como organizar a numeração auto-incremento de uma coluna Id de uma tabela no MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, auto-incremento

Gostaria de após cada inserção ou delete da minha tabela usar um script SQL para reorganizar os Ids.

Atualmente está mais ou menos assim:

```
Id Nome
 1 João
 3 José
 5 Ricardo
```

Quero deixar assim:

```
Id Nome
 1 João
 2 José
 3 Ricardo
```

Como fazer isso da melhor forma? (Não tenho chaves ligadas ao Id)

Comment: Isso me parece uma péssima prática. Tem algum motivo real ou é apenas curiosidade?

Comment: Cuidado com isso. Essa prática pode detonar seu banco de dados com relação a performance. Imagine que A pessoa de id = 3 esteja relacionada em mais 30 tabelas. Ao mudar o id de 3 para 2, todas os outros relacionamentos quebrariam com isso e um update nessas outras tabelas também seria necessário. Esse tipo de update não tem necessidade alguma de acontecer.

Comment: uaiHebert, como mencionei na questão não tenho chave nenhuma ligada ao Id. A tabela é pouco modificada e pouco acessada e sei que em na maioria dos casos não é uma boa prática. De qualquer forma obrigado pelas dicas.

Comment: Ia perguntar a mesma coisa, quando digitei o título da dúvida achei sua pergunta. Valeu!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Você pode usar o seguinte:

```sql
SET @count = 0;
UPDATE `tabela` SET `tabela`.`id` = @count:= @count + 1;
```

Exemplo completo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/750ce/1

(Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740358/mysql-reorder-reset-auto-increment-primary-key)

Comment: Obrigado! Simples e eficaz.

Comment: Só por curiosidade... como ficam as tabelas relacionadas?

Comment: Legal essa forma, não conhecia. Obrigado.

Comment: @NilsonUehara, essa mudança só funciona se não existirem tabelas relacionadas. Se existirem tabelas com chave estrangeira para esse id, o banco não deixa fazer o update.

Comment: Não tenha dor de cabeça apenas por perfeccionismo, o essencial é ser funcional, mesmo com alguns numeros da sequência faltando isso nao implica desorganização..

Comment: Usei só por capricho

Answer (score 2):

Existem 2 formas, mas ambas são custosas para usar no dia a dia.

Primeiramente vou usar como exemplo a sua situação, você deletou o id 4 nesse caso seria algo assim:

```
update tabela
set id = id - 1
where id > 4
```

Ou, quando for uma grande quantidade e você não souber exatamente quais foram deletados, o "certo" seria salvar seus dados um uma tabela temporária ou auxiliar.
Dropar sua tabela, e cria-la novamente com o id do 0. Mas não sei se é viável.
Ou ao invés de dropar a tabela inteira, simplesmente deletar os registros e zerar o auto increment do id assim:

```
ALTER TABLE 'tabela' AUTO_INCREMENT=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Meu conhecimento em SQL não é muito avançado mas tenho aprendido bastante.

```
DECLARE @W INT = 1
DECLARE @ID INT = 1
DECLARE @Max INT = (SELECT MAX ([ID]) FROM [_Table])
WHILE @W Between 1 and @Max 
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT [ID] FROM [_Table] WHERE [ID] = @W )
BEGIN
UPDATE [_Table] SET [ID] = @ID WHERE [ID] = @W 
SET @ID +=1
SET @W +=1
END
ELSE
SET @W +=1
END
```

Answer (score -1):

Relacionamento com `ON UPDATE CASCADE` as chaves parentes serão alteradas também:

```
CREATE TABLE child (
    id INT, 
    parent_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) 
        REFERENCES parent(id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Answer (score -3):

renomear id

```
update nome da sua tabela 
set id = '2'
where id = '3';

update nome da sua tabela 
set id = '5'
where id = '3';
```