# Como renumerar IDs de tabela no MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Apaguei da minha tabela de vendas os registros das vendas de teste feitas por mim, e as vendas canceladas. Então a numeração das vendas ficou desordenada, tipo: começa com 9, 10, 11, 14....Como faço para ordenar as vendas a partir do nº 1 e por aí adiante?

Comment: Dê mais detalhes de como está e onde você quer chegar. Na forma atual a pergunta não pode ser respondida.

Comment: Acredito que o que o @bigown está querendo saber é: como é essa coluna da "numeração"? É a chave primária? Tem autoincrement? Dito isso, em geral o ID da tabela acaba tendo esses buracos mesmo, eu deixaria como está.

Comment: `começa com 9, 10, 11, 14....` respondi, mas do 11 pulou pro 14?

Comment: @Edi.Gomes pelo que eu entendi esses id's apagados foram algumas vendas de teste que ele mesmo fez.

Comment: @Rodrigo Rigotti Isso mesmo que entendi, ele quer que comece do zero em produção, deve ter se confundido no exemplo.

Comment: Ainda acho que essa pergunta tem que ser reformulada, a questão toda ficou a maior bagunça.

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra solução para o cenário apresentado, **APENAS** se não existirem relacionamentos nesta tabela:

```
SET @contador = 0;
UPDATE `tabela_vendas` SET `tabela_vendas`.`id` = @contador := @contador + 1;
```

<sup>Fonte: [Como organizar a numeração auto-incremento de uma coluna Id de uma tabela no MySQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/601/como-organizar-a-numera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-auto-incremento-de-uma-coluna-id-de-uma-tabela-no-mys)</sup>

Após isto, execute o comando abaixo, *setando* novamente o número inicial do `auto_imcrement` para 0:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela_vendas AUTO_INCREMENT = 0
```

Comment: Lembrando que em seguida deve ser usado o ALTER TABLE mencionado pelo Edi, usando o **id maior + 1** como próximo AUTO_INCREMENT, senão vai ficar um "buraco" ao inserir o próximo registro.

Comment: @Bacco, bem lembrado. Vou acrescentar na minha resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que você quer reformular o `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Tente:

```
ALTER TABLE sua_tabela AUTO_INCREMENT = 0
```

Comment: Acredito que ele também queira renumerar os registros já existentes. Porém, vale discutir a validade de se fazer isso...